# Having morally wrong thoughts/ideas

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm searching for a good translation of:

"auf falsche Gedanken kommen"

or translated:

to get ethically/socially wrong thoughts, 
or planning/not rejecting the idea to do something illegal

is there a lean few word representation of that ?

Specifically in the sentence:

"They shouldn't air guys like that on television. Kids will get the wrong ideas."

Is this fitting and would be understood corretly?

Btw: [Another way of expressing "morally wrong" ideas](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/350076/another-way-of-expressing-morally-wrong-ideas) doesn't apply here, as it is more asking for "grey areas"

Comment: I suspect that most of the idioms in this area will have religious overtones.

Comment: Orwell suggested "ungoodthink", or "plus-ungoodthink" or even "double-plus-ungoodthink".

Comment: @HotLicks - No, this German idiom is intended in a joking manner.  Nothing religious about it.  Source: N. German spouse.

Comment: @aparente001 - But American and, to a lesser extent, British thought about morality is greatly influenced by Puritanism.

Comment: @HotLicks - You are welcome to write a Puritanical character with which you may attempt to sum up North American culture.  But don't give him the line "auf falsche Gedanken kommen" to say, because it wouldn't fit.

Comment: @aparente001 - I'm trying to explain why the idioms would tend toward the religious.

Comment: @HotLicks - Sorry, I'm not getting your idea.  You're trying to explain why *which* idioms would tend toward the religious?  (My point of view about this is that the original German idiom doesn't have a moralistic or religious undertone, and therefore we should match it up with an English idiom that doesn't have any of those undertones either.)

Comment: The problem is finding one.

Comment: @HotLicks - sorry, finding one what?  An idiom that expresses OP's phrase, in English?  I proposed two.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider "*getting **corrupted***" (in the moral sense).

> "They shouldn't air guys like that on television. Kids may get
>   ***corrupted***."

ODO:

> **[corrupt](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/corrupt)**
>   *VERB* [WITH OBJECT]. 
>   **1.1** Cause to become morally depraved:
>
> ‘he has ***corrupted*** the boy’
>
> ‘Ostensibly, we are protecting minors from being morally
>   ***corrupted*** by adults?’
>
> ‘Outside forces like the press and media could ***corrupt*** the young
>   boy, and John wished his son to have the most normal of childhoods, in
>   light of the circumstances.’

***Spoil*** may work too.

ODO:

> **[spoil](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spoil)**
>   *VERB*
>
> **2** Harm the character of (a child) by being too lenient or indulgent:
>
> ‘the last thing I want to do is spoil Thomas’
>
> ‘a spoilt child’
>
> ’‘They are spoiled rotten rich brats led by an attorney's son.’

Comment: I would say "kids may *be* corrupted", rather than "*get* corrupted".

Comment: And "spoil" doesn't seem to be addressing the issue at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposal "Kids will get the wrong ideas" is pretty close.  Two improvements will help.  (1) There is an idiom in English:

> *get the wrong idea (about someone or something)*: To develop a belief or impression (about someone or something) that is untrue, incorrect, or has been misinterpreted or misunderstood. Examples: *I feel like I need to explain my actions, or you'll end up getting the wrong idea about me. Now don't get the wrong idea or anything, but I think we should spend a little bit of time apart. Whoa, I think you've gotten the wrong idea about tonight—this wasn't supposed to be a date or anything like that!*

*([freedictionary.com](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+the+wrong+idea))*

(If you add the S as you did, you're not in the idiom anymore.)

2. Since, according to my German spouse, the original is intended in a joking way, *might* or *could* in place of *would* could help soften the expression and avoid a scolding tone.  So:

> "They shouldn't put people like that on a children's program. Kids could **get the wrong idea**."

Another possibility:

> Well, okay, you can watch that program this once.  **But don't go getting any bright ideas**.

If you really need the third person, okay, but the following is a little less effective:

> "I'd rather they didn't put people like that on television. **I wouldn't want my kids to get any bright ideas**."

Here, *bright ideas* is fondly sarcastic; it might reflect the joking tone of the original a little better.  I couldn't find a source for this one, though.  It's kind of like using *schlaue* in a fondly sarcastic way in "Du bist *so ein schlaue Bursche*."

(Note, *corrupt* and *spoil*, which were proposed in another answer, are too judgmental.)

Answer (score 1):

How about *bad influence*?

M-W:

> [*influence*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/influence):
>   one that exerts influence; the power to direct the thinking or
>   behavior of others usually indirectly

Your example:

"They shouldn't air guys like that on television. Kids will get the wrong ideas. He's a *bad influence*."